# Order independent transparency with MSAA

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have implemented OIT based on the demo in "OpenGL Programming Guide" 8th edition.(The red book).Now I need to add MSAA.Just enabling MSAA screws up the transparency as the layered pixels are resolved x times equal to the number of sample levels.I have read [this](http://www.yakiimo3d.com/2010/07/25/dx11-order-independent-transparency-with-msaa/) article on how it is done with DirectX where they say the pixel shader should be run per sample and not per pixel.How id it done in OpenGL.

I won't put out here the whole implementation but the fragment shader chunk in which the final resolution of the layered pixels occurs:

```
vec4 final_color = vec4(0,0,0,0);
for (i = 0; i < fragment_count; i++)
{
    /// Retrieving the next fragment from the stack:
    vec4 modulator = unpackUnorm4x8(fragment_list[i].y) ;
    /// Perform alpha blending:
    final_color =   mix(final_color, modulator, modulator.a);
}

color = final_color ;
```

**Update:**

I have tried the solution proposed here but it still doesn't work.Here  are the full fragment shader for the list build and resolve passes:

List build pass :

```
#version 420 core
layout (early_fragment_tests) in;
layout (binding = 0, r32ui) uniform uimage2D head_pointer_image;
layout (binding = 1, rgba32ui) uniform writeonly uimageBuffer list_buffer;
layout (binding = 0, offset = 0) uniform atomic_uint list_counter;
layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;//dummy output

in vec3 frag_position;
in vec3 frag_normal;
in vec4 surface_color;
in int gl_SampleMaskIn[];
uniform vec3 light_position = vec3(40.0, 20.0, 100.0);

void main(void)
{
    uint index;
    uint old_head;
    uvec4 item;
    vec4 frag_color;
    index = atomicCounterIncrement(list_counter);
    old_head = imageAtomicExchange(head_pointer_image, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), uint(index));

    vec4 modulator =surface_color;
    item.x = old_head;
    item.y = packUnorm4x8(modulator);
    item.z = floatBitsToUint(gl_FragCoord.z);
    item.w = int(gl_SampleMaskIn[0]);
    imageStore(list_buffer, int(index), item);
    frag_color = modulator;
    color = frag_color;
}
```

List resolve :

```
#version 420 core
// The per-pixel image containing the head pointers
layout (binding = 0, r32ui) uniform uimage2D head_pointer_image;
// Buffer containing linked lists of fragments
layout (binding = 1, rgba32ui) uniform uimageBuffer list_buffer;
// This is the output color
layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;
// This is the maximum number of overlapping fragments allowed
#define MAX_FRAGMENTS 40

// Temporary array used for sorting fragments
uvec4 fragment_list[MAX_FRAGMENTS];

void main(void)
{
    uint current_index;
    uint fragment_count = 0;
    current_index = imageLoad(head_pointer_image, ivec2(gl_FragCoord).xy).x;

    while (current_index != 0 && fragment_count < MAX_FRAGMENTS )
    {   
        uvec4 fragment = imageLoad(list_buffer, int(current_index));
        int coverage = int(fragment.w);
        //if((coverage &(1 << gl_SampleID))!=0) {

            fragment_list[fragment_count] = fragment;
            current_index = fragment.x;

        //}

        fragment_count++;
    }

    uint i, j;

    if (fragment_count > 1)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < fragment_count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = i + 1; j < fragment_count; j++)
            {
                uvec4 fragment1 = fragment_list[i];
                uvec4 fragment2 = fragment_list[j];

                float depth1 = uintBitsToFloat(fragment1.z);
                float depth2 = uintBitsToFloat(fragment2.z);

                if (depth1 < depth2)
                {
                    fragment_list[i] = fragment2;
                    fragment_list[j] = fragment1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    vec4 final_color = vec4(0,0,0,0);

    for (i = 0; i < fragment_count; i++)
    {  
        vec4 modulator = unpackUnorm4x8(fragment_list[i].y);
        final_color =  mix(final_color, modulator, modulator.a);      
    }

    color = final_color;
}
```

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing your complete code, but can't you do it the same way like in the linked DX11 demo? Just store the sample coverage in addition to the color and depth for each fragment in the store-pass and then let the final sorting and rendering shader run for each sample instead of just for each fragment, adding only the samples that are actually covered by the fragment.

Comment: "and then let the final sorting and rendering shader run for each sample instead of just for each fragment, adding only the samples that are actually covered by the fragment." That is what I don't understand how to do. How do I check the samples covered or not covered by the fragment?

Comment: In the same way the DX demo does, I guess. GLSL has the coverage mask and sample ID as fragment shader inputs, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing how your code actually works, you can do it very much the same way that your linked DX11 demo does, since OpenGL provides the same features needed.

So in the first shader that just stores all the rendered fragments, you also store the sample coverage mask for each fragment (along with the color and depth, of course). This is given as fragment shader input variable `int gl_SampleMaskIn[]` and for each sample with id `32*i+j`, bit `j` of `glSampleMaskIn[i]` is set if the fragment covers that sample (since you probably won't use >32xMSAA, you can usually just use `glSampleMaskIn[0]` and only need to store a single `int` as coverage mask).

```
...
fragment.color = inColor;
fragment.depth = gl_FragCoord.z;
fragment.coverage = gl_SampleMaskIn[0];
...
```

Then the final sort and render shader is run for each sample instead of just for each fragment. This is achieved implicitly by making use of the input variable `int gl_SampleID`, which gives us the ID of the current sample. So what we do in this shader (in addition to the non-MSAA version) is that the sorting step just accounts for the sample, by only adding a fragment to the final (to be sorted) fragment list if the current sample is actually covered by this fragment:

What was something like (beware, pseudocode extrapolated from your small snippet and the DX-link):

```
while(fragment.next != 0xFFFFFFFF)
{
    fragment_list[count++] = vec2(fragment.depth, fragment.color);
    fragment = fragments[fragment.next];
}
```

is now

```
while(fragment.next != 0xFFFFFFFF)
{
    if(fragment.coverage & (1 << gl_SampleID))
        fragment_list[count++] = vec2(fragment.depth, fragment.color);
    fragment = fragments[fragment.next];
}
```

Or something along those lines.

**EDIT:** To your updated code, you have to increment `fragment_count` only inside the `if(covered)` block, since we don't want to add the fragment to the list if the sample is not covered. Incrementing it always will likely result in the artifacts you see at the edges, which are the regions where the MSAA (and thus the coverage) comes into play.

On the other hand the list pointer has to be forwarded (`current_index = fragment.x`) in each loop iteration and not only if the sample is covered, as otherwise it can result in an infinite loop, like in your case. So your code should look like:

```
while (current_index != 0 && fragment_count < MAX_FRAGMENTS )
{
    uvec4 fragment = imageLoad(list_buffer, int(current_index));
    uint coverage = fragment.w;
    if((coverage &(1 << gl_SampleID))!=0)
        fragment_list[fragment_count++] = fragment;
    current_index = fragment.x;
}
```

Comment: " if(fragment.coverage & (1 << gl_SampleID))" this one throws an error of "uint to bool" cast error

Comment: @MichaelIV Well, then just explicitly say `(a & b) != 0`, I said it is just pseudocode. GLSL is much more strict with its type conversions than *C* and *C++*, it even might have problems with implicit `int` to `uint` casts.

Comment: Well,it's not really working so far.I am either getting infinit loop in the shader or the geometry edges are flickering.I will add the part where I retrieve the fragment.

Comment: @MichaelIV First of all the question, *does it actually work without MSAA already?*. Then it might be at the time to shown your complete code (at least the *complete* shader code).

Comment: Yes sure,it works perfectly without MSAA,It also works fine with MSAA but with effect of loosing transparancy. I will update the question with the full shader code for both passes.

Comment: @MichaelIV I don't know why it enters and infinite loop otherwise, but incrementing the `fragment_count` outside of the `if` is definitely wrong, because if the sample is not covered, we don't add the fragment to the `fragment_list` (and didn't assign reasonable values either), which might be the case why you're seeing strange artifacts at the edges (which are exactly the regions where coverage comes into play).

Comment: @MichaelIV Ok, found the reason for infinite loop.

Comment: Yes you are right but leaving the counter inside "if" statement causes the infinite loop...

Comment: @MichaelIV *"Yes you are right but leaving the counter inside "if" statement causes the infinite loop."* - See at the recent update.

Comment: Now the loop is ok.But the blending disappears as before.Which means the fragment_count is > 1

Comment: @MichaelIV Wut? You mean there isn't any blending or there isn't any antialiasing? And you used multisampling for both passes and sample shading for the resolve pass (i.e. got resonable coverage values into the fragment list)?

Comment: There is antialiasing.The blending loop (see the bottom of the second shader) probably runs more than 1 time.Do I have to enable sample shading only for the second pass?In terms of OpenGL what I do is binding FBO with MSAA for both build and resolve shaders passes and then just blit the result into the default FBO.

Comment: @MichaelIV *"Do I have to enable sample shading only for the second pass?"* - **Yes, yes, yes!** Both passes use mutlisampling (so your dummy renderbuffer in the first pass needs to be a multisample renderbuffer) but only the second pass uses sample shading. Just don't enable `GL_SAMPLE_SHADING` at all, the second pass will automatically use it, since it uses `gl_SampleID`, while the first pass doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelIV Glad we finally got it. And thanks for an interresting question, I've never delved into *order independent transparency* before.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenGL 4.3 [Spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.30.6.pdf) states in 7.1 about the `gl_SampleID` builtin variable:

> Any static use of this variable in a fragment shader causes the entire shader to be evaluated per-sample.

(This has already been the case in the ARB_sample_shading and is also the case for `gl_SamplePosition` or a custom variable declared with the `sample` qualifier)

Therefore it is quite automatic, because you will probably need the SampleID anyway.

Comment: Note: to manually enable per-sample shading, you `glEnable(GL_SAMPLE_SHADING)`.

Comment: I do enable sample shading.But the problem is that if I, for example have 2 fragments in the pixel list,when I set MSAA to be x2 the list contains 4 fragments as in the list build pass the multisamping inserts more than one for each fragment.Then in the resolve pass the blending happens more than once for each fragment and as a result of it the transparency is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelIV Of course you only use sample shading for the *resolve pass*, the previous *list build pass* runs only once for each fragment as usual and just records the coverage mask as given by `gl_SampleMaskIn`. See the linked DX11 demo and my (very similar) answer.

Comment: But shouldn't the build pass be also mutlisample to get gl_SampleMaskIn value?

Comment: @MichaelIV No, the `gl_SampleMaskIn` gives all the samples covered by this fragment (as a bitmask, i.e. bit i set -> sample i covered). Think about what would be the value when doing this per-sample, the sample mask would only have 1 single bit set, since a single sample, well, can only cover a single sample. You want a single coverage mask per-fragment.

Comment: @MichaelIV Maybe the key to your misunderstanding is that multisampling and per-sample shading are two different things. Of course the build pass should also use multisampled rendering, to get the sample mask computed appropriately, but it doesn't use per-sample shading. Normally when using multisampling you get a single fragment-shader invocation for each fragment and it stays this way for the build-pass. Sample-shading is a special feature (developed long after multisampling, and only core since 4.x) where the fragment shader is invoked for each sample and this we only need for the sort pass

Comment: @ChristianRau Yes.That is what I was talking about...I use custom FBOs and here is where my confusion is.The buld-pass frag shader uses uimageBuffer to store the fragments.The output color is "dummy" as it's masked with color mask...So from what you have said:this pass should be bound MSAA render buffer (or texture) as well as the sorting pass?Also, I thought the fragment shader in MSAA is invoced once for each MSAA level...

Comment: @MichaelIV The build pass doesn't write into an MSAA buffer either, since it uses some custom data structure to store the fragments. The build pass just needs to be invoked for each fragment, but with MSAA enabled so that it gets the `gl_SampleMaskIn` computed correctly by the rasterizer. But then it just records that sample mask per-fragment along with the other per-fragment values. It doesn't compute *or write out* anything per sample.

Comment: @MichaelIV Oh wait, yeah, I guess you still need to use an MSAA renderbuffer for the build pass in order for MSAA to actually be used, but of course you don't write anything into that buffer. The sorting pass then also uses MSAA and actually writes to an MSAA renderbuffer, as in any ordinary MSAA application (just that it uses sample shading).

Comment: @MichaelIV *"I thought the fragment shader in MSAA is invoced once for each MSAA level"* - In fact the whole point of MSAA and it's performance improvement over actual supersampling (rendering the complete scene in higer resolution and downsampling) is the fact that the heavy fragment shader is still only run once per-fragment. The per-sample colors of this fragment are then just taken from the per-fragment color, masked with the coverage mask computed by the rasterizer. But with the new per-sample shading you can get real supersampling.